# How to access sorted data in the GridJS library in the console after a sort event?

Tags: javascript, sorting, gridjs

I'm using the GridJS library to display a data grid on my web page. I've set the sorting option (sort) to true, and now I'm trying to access the sorted data in the browser console after a sorting event.

Here is the complete code snippet, including the data array:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gridjs/dist/gridjs.umd.js"></script>
```

```
const data = [
  { email: "john@example.com", name: "John", phoneNumber: "(353) 01 222 3333" },
  { email: "mark@gmail.com", name: "Mark", phoneNumber: "(01) 22 888 4444" },
  { email: "ener@gmail.com", name: "Ener", phoneNumber: "(55) 19 971 2821" },
  { email: "john@example.com", name: "John", phoneNumber: "(353) 01 222 3333" },
  { email: "mark@gmail.com", name: "Mark", phoneNumber: "(01) 22 888 4444" },
  { email: "ener@gmail.com", name: "Ener", phoneNumber: "(55) 19 971 2821" },
];

const grid = new gridjs.Grid({
  pagination: {
    limit: 10
  },
  sort: true,
  columns: ["name", "email", "phoneNumber"],
  data: data,
}).render(document.getElementById("grid"));

// Unfortunately, the 'sort' event doesn't provide direct access to the sorted data
// Here's the issue: in the console, I can't find any event that accesses the sorted data
grid.on('sort', (column, direction) => {
  console.log(`Sorted column: ${column}, Direction: ${direction}`);
  
  // I tried to access the sorted data using grid.config.data, but it doesn't work
  const sortedData = grid.config.data;
  console.log('Sorted data:', sortedData);
  
  // The question is: How can I correctly access the sorted data in the GridJS library in the console?
});
```

In the console, I can't find any event that provides direct access to the sorted data. How can I correctly access the sorted data in the GridJS library in the console?

Comment: where did you get the 'sort' event from? gridjs does not trigger such an event

Comment: In the documentation, I only found the 'rowclick' and 'cellclick' events (https://gridjs.io/docs/examples/event-handler), but I was trying something like sorting, hoping it would exist, haha. In the end, I just need an array with the data sorted the same way it is in the table.

Comment: I'm not sure about triggering the event on sorting, but you can get the data from `grid.config.store.state?.data.rows`

Comment: Interesting, this partially solves my problem. Since I'm using pagination with a limit of 10, only 10 data points are returned. Do you know how to return all the data sorted? Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I don't think it's possible. just think about it, gridjs allows for configuring async data sources where all pagination and sorting comes directly from the server, so it wouldnt make sense to load all the data onto the frontend. If you really need sorted data, just manually run the sort function yourself